# How to select a specific TitlePane inside an Accordion on buttonClick?

Tags: java, javafx

I've been working with JavaFX (using the SceneBuilder) to build a file-sharing system. My GUI shows all uploaded files on the side using a TitledPane for each, all of them organized in an Accordion.

[image: GUI]

On the click of the `Remove File` button I want to remove whichever TitledPane is "selected", which I would assume would be the one that is open (the expanded property) but it doesn't change to be considered expanded when I click on it. Normally when you click on a TitledPane in this situation, the bar opens downward and exposes its child nodes. I assumed this state would be considered expanded but I guess it isn't the case.

The onClick method:

```java
    public void removeFileClicked(){
        ObservableList<TitledPane> children = peersAccordion.getPanes();
        TitledPane removed = null;
        for(TitledPane p : children){
            if (p.isExpanded()) {
                TextArea a = (TextArea) p.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
                removeFileFromShared(a.getText().split("\n")[0]);
                removed = p;
                break;
            }
        }
        children.remove(removed);
    }
```

What can I do to fix this? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra I'm not sure what else I can do to make this reproducible. I followed the link you dropped but there isn't anything more I can provide, seeing as this is all the relevant code I use.

Comment: @VarianWrynn The difficulty is that, if somebody just copy-and-pasted your provided code and tried to compile and run it, it wouldn't work.  To reproduce your issue, more work is required, which decreases the chance of getting an accepted solution and increases the chance that what you are asking for is misunderstood.  For example, I didn't realize that JavaFX had a built-in Accordion control until I did some research into it and how it works, I had assumed that it was custom written by you, so my initial comments were wildly wrong, which is my mistake, but was preventable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example solution.

It shows an accordion in a scroll pane.

The items in the accordion can be added and removed using a button.
On add or removal, the next most relevant titled pane in the accordion is automatically expanded.

Additions occur at the end of the list.  The newly added pane in the list is the newly expanded one.

For removal, the newly expanded item is the prior element in the list (if it exists), or the next element if the removed element was the first in the list.  If the last pane is removed, then there are no expanded panes in the accordion.

If no titled pane is expanded, the "Remove" button is disabled, and remove is not possible, but "Add" is still possible and functions as described above.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class AccordionModification extends Application {

    private static final Lorem lorem = new Lorem();

    private static final double SPACING = 10;

    private static final int N_INITIAL_PANES = 5;
    private static final int N_WORDS_PER_PANE = 10;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
        IntStream.range(0, N_INITIAL_PANES).forEach(i ->
                accordion.getPanes().add(createTitledPane())
        );
        accordion.setExpandedPane(accordion.getPanes().get(0));

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(accordion);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> addPane(accordion, scrollPane));

        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setOnAction(e -> removePane(accordion));
        remove.disableProperty().bind(
                accordion.expandedPaneProperty().isNull()
        );

        HBox controls = new HBox(SPACING, add, remove);

        VBox layout = new VBox(SPACING, controls, scrollPane);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(SPACING));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addPane(Accordion accordion, ScrollPane scrollPane) {
        TitledPane newPane = createTitledPane();
        accordion.getPanes().add(newPane);
        accordion.setExpandedPane(newPane);
        newPane.requestFocus();

        scrollPane.applyCss();
        scrollPane.layout();

        scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVmax());
    }

    private void removePane(Accordion accordion) {
        TitledPane expandedPane = accordion.getExpandedPane();

        if (expandedPane != null) {
            int expandedIndex = accordion.getPanes().indexOf(expandedPane);
            accordion.getPanes().remove(expandedPane);

            int nPanes = accordion.getPanes().size();

            if (nPanes > 0) {
                TitledPane nextPane = accordion.getPanes().get(
                        Math.max(0, expandedIndex - 1)
                );

                accordion.setExpandedPane(
                        nextPane
                );

                nextPane.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    private TitledPane createTitledPane() {
        return new TitledPane(
                lorem.nextWord(),
                createTitledPaneContent()
        );
    }

    private Parent createTitledPaneContent() {
        Label content = new Label(lorem.nextText(N_WORDS_PER_PANE));
        content.setWrapText(true);
        StackPane container = new StackPane(content);
        container.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

        return container;
    }

    // class for generating example text for test data, not integral to the solution.
    private static final class Lorem {
        private static final String[] lorem = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua".split(" ");
        private int idx = 0;

        public String nextWord() {
            return lorem[getAndIncrementIdx()];
        }

        public String nextText(int nWords) {
            return IntStream.range(0, nWords)
                    .mapToObj(i -> nextWord())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        }

        private int getAndIncrementIdx() {
            int retVal = idx;

            idx = (idx + 1) % lorem.length;

            return retVal;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A bit verbose, but I think I get it. Accordion has a  `.getExpandedPane()` method huh? Makes sense why I couldn't find anything I was only looking at the TitledPanes. Thanks! It probably works, but something else in the process broke so I'm not 100% yet. I wasn't getting any errors before though so that's progress.

Comment: I don’t know what is broken for you, my example works fine for me.